# How could I set up an app.compat actionbar toolbar without extending actionbaractivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am already extending another class (expandablelistactivity) but I need a toolbar in my activity. Is there a way around this?

Usually I use toolbar in combination with:

```
setSupportActionbar()
```

in my activity. And in the xml for my activity, I'll use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
```

And in my apptheme, I'll set it to no actionbar as so:

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Folks are suggesting that I

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
```

However, it says won't be resolved ("cannot resolve appcompatdelegate"). I have updated my Android Support Repository and Android Support Libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AppCompatDelegate` with matching activity lifecycle callbacks for anything related to action bar.

From [Chris Banes' blog](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/):

> There is a contract to maintain when you create a delegate. You must
>   callback to it at every call it exposes (for instance `onCreate()`), but
>   it’s really simple and can be extracted into a base class.
>
> The end result is that you can attach all of AppCompat’s functionality
>   to any Activity sub-class, as long as you call it as it wants.

Check out [this example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/7200281446186c7192cb02f54dc2b38e02d705e5/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java) of `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`, extending the no action bar `PreferenceActivity`, and using `AppCompatDelegate` to provide action bar.

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate; doesn't work

Comment: You need to update you Android Support Repository and Android Support Library to latest version (22.1.0).

Comment: I have version 22.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The 22.1 release of the v4 support library offers the new [`AppCompatDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html?utm_campaign=ASL221-415&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog). `AppCompatDelegate` now exposes methods like `setSupportActionbar()` that before were part of `ActionBarActivity`.

Here is the blog [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) from Google where `AppCompatDelegate` is introduced if you need more information.